# Can I control the version of Gradle used in Docker Hub builds?

Tags: gradle, dockerhub

I have a GitHub repo that built successfully 24 days ago.  Today, I can't get it to build.  I finally noticed that it built okay with Gradle 8.0.2, but it failed when Gradle 8.1.1 was used.

The repo is unchanged.  The git hash is the same.  It seems that Docker Hub is keeping Gradle up-to-date, and something broke because of it.

Is there any way for me to make Docker Hub use an older version of Gradle?

Comment: Are you sure Gradle is actually fully installed, and not installed on first use or somesuch?  You don't provide a Dockerfile or a base image, so it's hard to know for certain.  I believe the hash is a checksum, so the question statement seems somewhat suspect.  Also, I don't think Docker Hub is in the habit of maintaining versions in images...?

Comment: You're implying that it's my code that's changing the version of Gradle?  I am taking over an unfamiliar codebase, so you may be right.  I'm just not sure how... unless somewhere in the code it's referring to latest, and that's how the version of Gradle is changing.  Thanks for pointing this out.  You've given me a needed clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to my inexperience with this codebase, I thought that Docker Hub was running gradle *on* my code, but it was actually me running gradle *inside* of my code.  All I had to do was modify the first line of my Dockerfile.

Before:

```
FROM gradle:jdk17 AS build
```

After:

```
FROM gradle:7.6.1-jdk17 AS build
```

I am willing to show my ignorance just to help the next guy. :-)

I will say that the errors that I ran into were quite baffling.  It was far from obvious what the cause was.  I wish I had captured the errors.  At one point, I was getting an error in my logs about org.h2.jdbc and CREATE EXTENSION, even though I was using Postgres.  The fix for that was a change to the version of

```
classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.5.5")
```

Go figure.